# Calling password_hash multiple times throws 503

Tags: php

I have a large number of users and I want to change theirs passwords to a more secure hash.

However, if `$users` is an array with more than 1250 elements, my Vagrant throws a 503. I tried to increase the number of cores for the VM, but the result is the same.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $password = password_hash($user['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
}
```

Comment: Did you already tried increase memory config into your php.ini file?

Comment: yep, I set it to: `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`